# Oracle Apex Import csv file

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have an issue when importing a CSV file into the Oracle APEX application. It is unable to load characters with punctuation marks for Serbian and Croatian languages. When I perform the import through Google Docs and save the file as CSV, it imports successfully with punctuation marks. However, when I do the same with Excel, I encounter a problem where it fails to recognize punctuation marks and replaces them with question marks, exclamation marks, and similar symbols. Can you please provide assistance?

I tried to adjust the language settings on the computer, and in addition to that, I configured APEX to perform encoding in UTF-8.

Comment: What is **database's** character set? Is it capable of properly displaying these characters?

Comment: The database character set is AL32UTF8.

Answer (score 0):

With sample csv file data:
ID;TEST
1;ćĆ čČ đĐ šŠ žŽ

If you want to import a csv file as a file in an application then:

- go to Shared components
- click Static Application Files
- click Create File button
- click drag and drop and choose your file or just drag and drop it
- click Create

[image]

If you want to load your csv data into a table then:

- from SQL Workshop - Utilities - click Data Workshop
- click Load Data
- drag and drop file
- enter Table Owner and Table Name
- change File Encoding to UTF-8  - Preview should change
- click Load Data

[image]